# Vertically centering a container

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm working on my portfolio currently, and trying to vertically center my sections and make them responsive. But nothing works, I can center them horizontally but when I try to use position: relative and top: 50%.. Nothing happens. I'm going to put my code and my codepen here.

HTML:

```
<section id="intro">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div id="intro-cont">
              <h1>
                I'm Peter, an upcoming Front-End Developer, gamer and lo-fi lover.
              </h1>
              <a class="animated infinite bounce delay-10s" id="more" href="#about">More<br><i class="arrow down"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

css:

```
/*** Intro ***/

#intro{
  height: 90vh;
}

#intro-cont{
    text-align: center;
  positio
}

#intro-cont h1 {
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: 0;
  left:0;
}

#intro-cont i {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#intro-cont .down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#intro-cont a {
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

The weird thing is that in Codenpen it works perfectly.. but in JSFiddle, where my whole project is.. it doesn' work..

Links:

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Sarithan/pen/eLXzva

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Sarithan/pgjehwbv/

Comment: Hmm it looks centered decently to me even in jsfiddle

Comment: I'm trying to vertically center it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the height on `#intro-cont` and a `position: relative;` for this to work. 
See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u85ekcg0/

Comment: Can you please also tell me how I can center the whole #about-cont? And is position: absolute the best way to do this?

Comment: Frankly position absolute isn't the best way to center things, you can look at using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) and [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) 

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Umm, last question, is height: 100vh, the best way to make sections a certain height?

Comment: `height: 100vh` sets the height to 100% of the viewport height, [more about viewports here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/viewport)